# Convex polyhedron in lattice points

Tags: discrete-geometry, lattices

Given $P$ a convex polyhedron with  vertices in lattice points with $n$ faces.

a) what is the minimum volume of $P$.

b) what is the minimum area  surface of $P$.

Paper: The minimum area of convex lattice $n$-gons